# Should I copy appsetting.json to coutput directory in order to update configuration after dotnet publish

Tags: .net, configuration

I just want to update appsetting.json after dotnet webapi published.
should I use appsetting.json to do this?

Comment: In fact, I found that it's quite different between `dotnet build` and `dotnet publish`. 
In `dotnet build`, the build tool won't copy appsetting.json file to Debug folder. And the debug command is `dotnet run ProjectName.csproj`.
In `dotnet publish`, the build tool will copy appsetting.json file to Publish folder. Then the run command is `dotnet ProjectName.dll` for the build result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just left it where it is at the project folder.  in asp.net core 2.0, you do not need to do anything about its location or add the file in code.

In test environment, you need to find the appsetting.json file in code.  I can post the code here if you need which I modified from Microsoft Docs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I have the gender way to fix it in my question comments.